Converting json file to avro scheme using pyspark
I want to create an avro schema based on json documents. Here is the example of json record that I have.
{"_id": "66eb0139f16c486824ac839e", "parent_id": "66eb0139f16c486824ac839b", "creation_date": "2024-09-18T16:35:05.667Z", "parcel_number": "MP6422003-001", "merchant_id": "3517"}

From this json I need to obtain classical avro schema with data types as the following.
{
     "type": "record",
     "namespace": "com.example",
     "name": "FullName",
     "fields": [
       { "name": "_id", "type": "string" },
       { "name": "merchant_id", "type": "numeric" }
     ]
} 

I have written the following code that uses pyspark:
import os, avro.datafile
import pyspark
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SQLContext


appName = "PySpark SQL Server"
master = "local"
conf = SparkConf() \
    .setAppName(appName) \
    .setMaster(master) \
    .set("spark.driver.memory", "4g")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
spark = sqlContext.sparkSession


spark.read.json('input.json').coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save("output.avro")

avrofile = list(filter(lambda file: file.startswith('part-00000'), os.listdir('output.avro')))[0]

with open('output.avro/' + avrofile, 'rb') as avrofile:
    reader = avro.datafile.DataFileReader(avrofile, avro.io.DatumReader())
    schema = reader.meta['avro.schema']
    print(schema)

But thе result of this code doesn't contain any specific data types from my json. The data type in the resulting avro schema is always string.
The result:
b'{"type":"record","name":"topLevelRecord","fields":[{"name":"_id","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"creation_date","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"merchant_id","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"parcel_number","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"parent_id","type":["string","null"]}]}'

How can I fix this and obtain avro schema with correct data types?
Also, how could I rewrite my code so the final result will be the formated avro schema (not in one line)? And how can I get rid of the step with the saving the output.avro file localy?
